# Capturing audio in Docker

Tags: docker

I would like to be able to run multiple docker instances on a larger server, where each docker instance is running an internet browser and audio is being streamed through the browser. Each docker instance/browser is capturing audio coming through that browser. This is in place of running multiple vms where each vm is running a browser, capturing audio (using it's distinct virtual sound card) that is being played in the browser. Is this possible with docker?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to use pulseaudio like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985714/run-apps-using-audio-in-a-docker-container). Then you can setup VLC to record a network stream from pulseaudio.